# Basic concept behind Video streaming

Tags: java, audio, video, streaming, webcam

Can anyone tell me the basic steps of streaming. Like taking a stream of video from webcam and send it to a webpage. I want to program in java. Just need the idea of how a stream is done. Like how the data is stored and sent ?

Comment: A question like this and 2 immediate upvotes ? what is this voodoo ?

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article section [Streaming media: Codec, bitstream, transport, control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Codec.2C_bitstream.2C_transport.2C_control) should be the ideal starting point, as it answers your question rather well, and provides links to used technologies for further reference.

Comment: Thanks , got some basic idea.

The audio stream is compressed using an audio codec such as MP3, Vorbis or AAC.
The video stream is compressed using a video codec such as H.264 or VP8.
Encoded audio and video streams are assembled in a container bitstream such as FLV, WebM, ASF or ISMA.
The bitstream is delivered from a streaming server to a streaming client using a transport protocol, such as MMS or RTP.
The streaming client may interact with the streaming server using a control protocol, such as MMS or RTSP.

Comment: The [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411881/1468366#comment16681951_12411881) is mostly a verbatim quotation from the Wikipedia article in the answer. @Sourav, be careful to properly attribute such content, as [Wikipedia's CC-BY_SA License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:CC-BY-SA) requires!

Comment: alternatively the compressed video/audio data format can be transported over HTTP as a series of short (~6 second) files, take a look at HTTP Live Streaming

Comment: @EventHorizon, would you write that as a separate answer?

Comment: @MvG , ok i will be careful , thanks.